# Using Guid as Primary & Foreign Key Sqllite C#

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, guid

One of my senior developer is suggesting to use C# Guid as Primary Key & foreign key in Sqllite Db.

Is it a good idea to use Guid as Primary Key & foreign key?

Comment: IS there a particular problem using an auto-increment integer that the GUID solves?

Comment: yes, the same Guid used for other purpose as well like generating QR code using Guid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pros:
the primary key can be generated on the client side during creation instead of sending it back to the server first. This way you can do other stuffs using the ID without it even exists in the DB

Cons:
Once the server receives it you need to check! just in case you run into the possibility of winning a lottery (1/2^128)

Uses more spaces for both storage and index page. And potentially slightly slower (not notably) performance.